# Excluding last row during sort

Tags: vba, ms-word

I solved my problem without needing to Cut, Sort, or insert the row back by adjusting my forloop on AddArrayName to count and populate in ascending order.

```
Sub AddArrayName()
With ActiveDocument

Dim tbl As Object
Dim noOfCol As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer

j = cbArraySize.Value

Set tbl = .Tables(2)
    With tbl
        noOfCol = tbl.Range.Rows(1).Cells.Count
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            With .Rows(i)
                If Len(.Range) = noOfCol * 2 + 2 Then 
.Cells(1).Range.InsertAfter Text:=tbArrayName.Text + " - " & j + 1
            End With
        j = j - 1
        Next i

End With
End With
End Sub
```

I have a dynamic table that creates x rows and auto populates the first cell based on user input.  Once named, I exclude the header and sort the rows.  The last row needs to be excluded from the sort as it contains "Notes:".

I believe I would need a for loop to get the last row -1, but unable to wrap my head around it or where to get started as I am new to VBA and still trying to learn the basics.

`Sub TableSort()
ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Sort ExcludeHeader:=True
End Sub`

This is what I currently have which is broken into separate Subs.  I have it working except it inserts the range **before** the last row.

```
Private Sub cbArraySize_Click()

If cbArraySize.Value <> 0 Then

DeleteRows
CutRow2
AddRows
AddArrayName
TableSort
InsertRow2

End If

End Sub

Sub DeleteRows()

Dim tbl As Word.Table
Dim nrRows As Long, ColToCheck As Long, i As Long
Dim cellRange As Word.Range

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
nrRows = tbl.Rows.Count - 1
ColToCheck = 2

For i = nrRows To 1 Step -1
    Set cellRange = tbl.Cell(i, ColToCheck).Range
    If Len(cellRange.Text) = 2 Then
        cellRange.Rows(1).Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub CutRow2()

With ActiveDocument

.Tables(2).Rows(2).Select
Selection.Cut
End With

End Sub 

Sub AddRows()

With ActiveDocument

.Tables(2).Rows(1).Select
Selection.InsertRowsBelow (cbArraySize.Value)

End With

End Sub

Sub AddArrayName()
With ActiveDocument

Dim tbl As Object
Dim noOfCol As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim intcount As Integer

intcount = 1

Set tbl = .Tables(2)
    With tbl
        noOfCol = tbl.Range.Rows(1).Cells.Count
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            With .Rows(i)
                If Len(.Range) = noOfCol * 2 + 2 Then 
.Cells(1).Range.InsertAfter Text:=tbArrayName.Text + " - " & intcount
            intcount = intcount + 1
            End With
        Next i
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Then I sort the table excluding headers.

```
InsertRow2()

Dim mytable As Object
Set mytable = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)

mytable.Rows(mytable.Rows.Count).Range.Paste

End Sub
```

After the InsertRow2() sub routine it inserts the range before the last row.

Example of table:[End Table Result I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYcJk.jpg)

What it actually does: [Actual Table Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90JdZ.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word Macro: How exclude total row in table sort & Get rid of Error 5992](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049229/word-macro-how-exclude-total-row-in-table-sort-get-rid-of-error-5992)

Comment: At the beginning of the question it says you solved the problem. Is it solved? Then the solution should be in an Answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rule of thumb for VBA: If you can't do it as an end-user, VBA probably can't do it, either. Word's built-in Sort command can only exclude the header row, but not rows at the end of the table.

As far as I know, the only way you could work around this would be to split this last row off as a separate table. That will put a paragraph mark between, but that can be formatted with "hidden" font formatting so that the two tables will look like one table. That will enable you to sort the table without the "notes", as illustrated below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cindy.  I will try your suggestion and see if I can figure out that work around.

Comment: Let me know if you need more detailed instructions... @Sparks

Comment: Right now I'm trying to use .Tables(2).Rows(2).Cut (could always use copy then delete Row(2), Then I sort the table.  How would I paste this range after the last row? @Cindy Meister

Comment: @Sparks : You're not the person in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049229/word-macro-how-exclude-total-row-in-table-sort-get-rid-of-error-5992? They appeared so close together, I figured you tried again, under a different name. The code in that Answer shows how.

Comment: Nope not me.  I have been looking at the answer trying to decipher it to apply it to mine. @Cindy Meister

Comment: Cindy I added the code that I currently have as I am unable to figure out how to apply it to mine.  Any help would be appreciated. @Cindy Meister