# Word Macro: How exclude total row in table sort & Get rid of Error 5992

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using macro to sort tables in a Word file with multiple tables, it works great but lamentably sort the total row too, all the tables have different row count, tables after and before sort are:

**Table Examples Pre-sort:**

[image: pre sort]

[image: other example]

**Post-sort:**

[image: post sort]

The macro is: (thanks to @scenography for that)

```
Dim mytable As Table
For Each mytable In ActiveDocument.Tables
mytable.Sort ExcludeHeader:=True, FieldNumber:="Column 2", _
    SortFieldType:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric,      SortOrder:=wdSortOrderDescending
Next
```

Any way to achieve this ?

**EDIT:**

Could avoid last row (Total) with this line? example:

```
 Dim last_row As Long last_row = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row )
```

or

```
 lLastRow = rng(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Row
```

Its possible remove last column(Cum), because when sort this value its not correct.

Here a link with a word document with example of my tables to replicate results

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KpV11dHjON_gFnlAvlegzc3pWVfYipV4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot exclude the Last Row from `Sort`, but this workaround will work, if it is always the Total Row.

```
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

Set mytable = ActiveDocument.Tables(i)

mytable.Rows(mytable.Rows.Count).Delete

mytable.Sort ExcludeHeader:=True, FieldNumber:="Column 2", _
    SortFieldType:=wdSortFieldNumeric, SortOrder:=wdSortOrderDescending

mytable.Rows(2).Range.Copy
mytable.Rows.Add
mytable.Rows(mytable.Rows.Count).Range.Paste
mytable.Rows(2).Delete

mytable.Cell(1, mytable.Columns.Count).Select
Selection.SelectColumn
Selection.Cells.Delete ShiftCells:=wdDeleteCellsShiftLeft

Next
```

Basically we are moving the Second row to the Last row after sorting.

**Tables Look like:**
[image]

Comment: Yes, Added the extra line in the Answer. Accept the answer if it works for you :) @RODRIGO

Comment: Gave error, only remove first value from last column and stop the macro

Comment: Didn't understand what you exactly want. Post the screenshot in Question for it.

Comment: I attach some example with table with column removed

Comment: This line will remove last column `mytable.Columns(mytable.Columns.Count).Delete` , what is the error  ? @RODRIGO

Comment: See the Edit in Answer.  @RODRIGO

Comment: Could use a range to avoid last row? macro not work in all tables, sort total row: Sub CountRows1()
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    )
End Sub

Comment: other line to identify last row: lLastRow = rng(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Row

Comment: @RODRIGO ... I have amended the code. And it runs on the Sample provided by you. The Issue was you were using `AlphaNumeric` sort for numbers, and your tables had a blank row at the End. This code is working fine now. If you have any more question, i would suggest you to ask a new question. Hope it helps you.